# Assigning a minimum value in a scrollbar fires the scrollbar change event, but assigning a maximum value does not

Tags: excel, vba, events, scrollbar

I am unsure why setting the `scrollbar.Min` property fires the event when I assign a value to it, but the `scrollbar.Max` property does not fire the event when I assign a value to it.

The code used is below:

```
Me.scrPieces.Min = frmSettings.tbxPiecesLow.Value
Me.scrPieces.Max = frmSettings.tbxPiecesHigh.Value
Me.scrPieces.SmallChange = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((frmSettings.tbxPiecesHigh.Value - frmSettings.tbxPiecesLow.Value) / 40, 0)
Me.scrPieces.LargeChange = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((frmSettings.tbxPiecesHigh.Value - frmSettings.tbxPiecesLow.Value) / 8, 0)
```

When I step through `Me.scrPieces.Min = frmSettings.tbxPiecesLow.Value` and it assigns a value to it, the `scrPieces.Change()` event fires:

```
Private Sub scrPieces_Change()
i = Me.scrPieces.Min
j = 0

Me.tbxPiecesD = Me.scrPieces.Value

Do While i <= Me.scrPieces.Max
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Simulation-Chart").Cells(2 + j, 1) = i
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Simulation-Chart").Cells(2 + j, 2) = (CostPerPiece * (Me.scrFoilMarkup.Value / BigNum) + LaborCostPerPiece * (Me.scrLaborMarkup.Value / BigNum)) * (Me.scrQuoteMarkup.Value / BigNum)
    i = i + (Me.scrPieces.Max - Me.scrPieces.Min) / 10
    j = j + 1
Loop

MyChart.Export Filename:=ImgName, FilterName:="GIF"
Me.imgChart.Picture = LoadPicture(ImgName)

End Sub
```

But when I step through `Me.scrPieces.Max`, it will not activate the `scrPieces.Change()` event and simply move to the next line.

Refer below for the photographs:

Stepping through the code, after a value is assigned to `scrPieces.Min`, as shown below:
[image]

The `scrPieces_Change()` event will fire
[image]

However, assigning `scrPieces.Max` will not fire the event.
[image]

The code will immediately move to the next line as shown below:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand. You set a value in the field and you somehow want this to mean the maximum value that field can hold?

Comment: I would probably just use the textbox_change. If the value is over your max then make it max value. Far simpler in my opinion.

Comment: Revised the question apologies. I believe the issue lies in the scrollbar `change` event it is very odd

Comment: @urdearboy I would want to do that but i'm unsure how i'm going to demonstrate the stepping through of the VBE

Comment: @urdearboy I edited and added both the code and photo since I think they make it easier to understand.

Comment: Pictures of code is crap!

Comment: @Andreas sorry for that it's clear when you press on it. It just appears distorted at the display, but the idea is there

Comment: What is the value of `Me.scrPieces.Max` *before* you assign it?  If you are assigning it a value it already has, nothing will change.  Also, what is  `Me.scrPieces.Value` through all of this?  Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/change-event , onChange is tied to `Value`, not to `Min` or `Max`.  I believe the only reason you get `onChange` when you change `Min` is because doing so also adjusts `Value` as a side effect.

Comment: @cxw That makes sense. `Me.scrPieces.Max` actually works. It was initially set at 2,500,000 prior to running the code, then it changes to 10,000 after I run the code. I did not set `Me.scrPieces.Value` when the code in the main post was ran. The code that has a `Me.scrPieces.Value` assignment that is after the troubled portion is ran. `Me.scrPieces.Value` = `Me.scrPieces.Min`

Comment: I believe since `Me.scrPieces.Min` is set initially to 0 (and probably `Me.scrPieces.Value` is also defaulted to 0), setting `Me.scrPieces.Min`  to a value greater than 0 will shift `Me.scrPieces.Value` and trigger the change event. Thanks that explains it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/change-event), the `Change` event is tied to the scrollbar's `Value`, *not* to its `Max` or `Min`.  I believe the only reason you get `onChange` when you change `Min` is because doing so also adjusts `Value` as a side effect.

If you want to make sure `scrPieces_Change` is called, you can actually call it directly after you set the `Min` and `Max`.  It's just a regular function, so `Call scrPieces_Change` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments earlier.
Use textbox_change and if the value is above your limit then set the value to the limit.

```
Private Sub scrPieces_Change()
    If Me.scrPieces.Value > YourLimit Then
        Me.scrPieces.Value = YourLimit
    End If
End Sub
```

If this limit is set in the initialize, then make a global variable that you can assign this value too.
This way it will be accessible in scrPieces_Change

Comment: Thanks i'll check if it's applicable in my case